# En php "->" lo marca como texto

Tags: php

Tengo este código PHP:

```
<?php

    $automovil1 = (object)["marca"=>"toyota", "modelo"=>"carolla"];
    $automovil2 = (object)["marca"=>"hyundai","modelo"=>"accent vicion"];

    function mostrar($automovil){

        echo "<p> Hola! soy un $automovil->marca, modelo $automovil->modelo</p>";

    }


    mostrar($automovil1);

?>
```

Comment: Imagino que este no es exactamente el código en el que te ocurre el problema que comentas. ¿Podrías compartir el código exacto? Pensando en ejemplos de uso me he fijado que tu caso en particular no debería dar problemas.

Comment: Prueba a encerrar la variable entre {} así "un {$automovil->marca}," o usa sprintf(" lo que sea %s funcionará", $var)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema que podrías tener cuando te aparece `->` o cualquier otra cosa como texto es que no estás delimitando la variable, propiedad, llamada a función, etc entre llaves (usando tanto la [sintaxis simple](http://php.net/es/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple) como la [sintaxis compleja](http://php.net/es/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.complex)) para evitar confusiones tal y como te indican en la [documentación de "análisis de variables"](http://php.net/es/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing):

> **Sintaxis simple**
>
> Si se encuentra un signo de dólar (`$`), el analizador *tomará el mayor número de símbolos para formar un nombre de variable válido*. Delimitar el nombre de la variable con llaves permite especificar explícitamente el final del nombre.
>
> **Sintaxis compleja (llaves)**
>
> Cualquier variable escalar, elemento de `array` o propiedad de objeto con una representación de tipo `string` puede ser incluido a través de esta sintaxis.
>
> Simplemente se escribe la expresión del mismo modo en que aparecería por fuera del `string`, y delimitándola con `{` y `}`.

Es decir, tu cadena `"... soy un $automovil->marca, ..."` se interpreta como que `$automovil` es una variable y, aunque el carácter `-` no puede formar parte del nombre de una variable, el analizador entiende que tratas de mostrar una propiedad por tener `->`.

Si en vez de eso tuvieras `"... soy un $automovil -> marca, ..."` (con espacios en blanco antes o después del `->`) cambiaría el asunto porque el analizador entendería que la variable termina al aparecer el espacio en blanco y deberías usar `"... soy un {$automovil -> marca}, ..."` para delimitar claramente el conjunto que quieres mostrar. Usar `"... soy un ${automovil -> marca}, ..."` (sintaxis simple) no funcionaría en este caso.

Para evitar problemas de interpretación tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$automovil1 = (object)[
  "marca" => "toyota",
  "modelo" => "carolla",
];
$automovil2 = (object)[
  "marca" => "hyundai",
  "modelo" => "accent vicion",
];

/* Usando llaves para delimitar variable y propiedad */
function mostrar($automovil) {
  echo "<p> Hola! soy un {$automovil->marca}, modelo {$automovil->modelo}</p>", PHP_EOL;
}

/* Usando separador (también se podría concatenar) */
function mostrar2($automovil) {
  echo "<p> Hola! soy un ", $automovil->marca, ", modelo ", $automovil->modelo, "</p>", PHP_EOL;
}

mostrar($automovil1);
mostrar2($automovil2);
```